# Angular bind string when passing URL

Tags: angularjs

How can I bind a string that lives in a API URL when clicking from one `href` to go to another `href` in angular. What is the best method? Had thought `ng-click` may be a good way to do this, but without a named property, I am not sure.

Comment: Do you mean something like `ng-click='window.location={{ someURLvariable }}'` ?

Comment: @Mark, could you please explain your problem with an example? I mean, if you specifies how will be your href users can easily help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Please add code which you have try. Without your code not possible give proper ans.

Comment: @JavierConde - yes, kind of like that, but there is only a path, not a window and the variable has no name. So would be host/path/path and what is returned is a simple string with no property name. Could be a JSON object in that sense though. Ideas? Thanks much.

Comment: Oh, and how can I keep this going from one location within the angular app to another? What I mean is, if I store the method in a controller that is not shared, that won't work. So in that case, what is the best approach with the angular way?